# Add two ActiveRecord::Relation / scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have two scopes.

```
scope :has_food_preference, -> { where.not(food_preference: nil) }

scope :wine_chosen, -> { where(relationship: 1, company_size: 1).where.not(wine_id: nil) }
```

So basically it's a program to organize christmas gifts for a company's customers (i do this for my father's company just for fun).

The scope `has_food_preference` is pretty straight forward; vegetarian, vegan, etc.
Then the scope `wine_chosen`: only companies with a `relationship: 1` and `company_size: 1` will get a wine (per person that's why size matters), so the `wine_id` also cannot be empty.

How can I combine these two scopes?

At the end I want "All companies where `food_preference` is set and where `wine_id` is set if `relationship: 1` and `company_size: 1`".

I tried many different things.

**Option 1**:

```
Customer.where.not(food_preference: nil).or(Customer.where(relationship: 1, company_size: 1).where.not(wine_id: nil))
```

--> Does not work. Completely ignores the `or` and only returns `where.not(food_preference: nil)`

**Option 2**:

```
companies = has_food_preference + wine_chosen
```

--> return Array. I want a ActiveRecord::Relation

**Option 3**:

```
scope :food_and_wine, -> { self.has_food_preference.merge(self. wine_chosen) }
```

--> Merge somehow acts like AND, but I want OR

**Option 4**:
Something with `arel_table`. Had the same result as Option 1.

---

So HOW do I combine these two? It can't be that hard, right???

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the data (use a simple ASCII table) and what you expect the result of the query to be? It makes it so much easier to answer the question and removes the ambigiouty about what you expect the result to be. Please respond by editing the question and not by comment.

Comment: `where(arel_table[:food_preference].not_eq(nil).or(arel_table[:relationship].eq(1).and( arel_table[:company_size].eq(1)).and(arel_table[:wine_id].not_eq(nil))))` will producer `WHERE customers.food_preference IS NOT NULL OR (customers.relationship = 1 AND customers.company_size = 1 AND customers.wine_id IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to work:

```
scope :food_and_wine, -> { has_food_preference.or(self.wine_chosen) }
```